Why doesn't TypeScript infer the most narrow type declaration?
Why doesn't TypeScript emit "a" | "b" for the type of test2? My IDE's IntelliSense correctly infers that test2 is of type of "a" | "b", but the emitted type declaration is just "string".
// index.ts
export const test1 = true ? ('a' as const) : ('b' as const);
export const test2 = true ? 'a' : 'b';

// index.d.ts
export declare const test1: "a" | "b";
export declare const test2: string;

// tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "composite": true,
    "emitDeclarationOnly": true,
  }
}

StackBlitz Link

The TypeScript compiler doesn't infer this specific type because the declaration file specifies a broader string type.

^ @huanfeng The question doesn't make it clear, but the declaration file is generated from the TypeScript source file. What's being asked is: "Why is the typeof test2 being inferred as string instead of "a" | "b" during declaration emit for index.ts?"

@DennisKats Somewhat related to your question: you can control declaration emit for non-trivial inference by using explicit annotations, and the compiler can help enforce this (since v5.5) by using isolatedDeclarations (release notes)

@jsejcksn yea I've already begun looking into isolatedDeclarations as a result of this issue. But I'm still trying to find a documented reason for why IntelliSense and the declarations file infer different types in this case.

^ @DennisKats It seems like a bug to me. Here's a TS playground link that includes a reproduction of your claim. Activating the .d.ts view in the right-side panel will display the declaration emit from the playground source code. This eliminates the need for third-party tools (e.g. StackBlitz) which increase complexity in the reproduction.

Using type and typeof tp debug it:
export const test1 = true ? ('a' as const) : ('b' as const);
type T1 = typeof test1; // 'a' | 'b'
export const test2 = true ? 'a' : 'b';
type T2 = typeof test2; // 'a' | 'b'

In both cases, the type is 'a' | 'b'. Is TypeScript ignoring true ? in the conditional expression. It is simply inferring the type In both sides of the expression 'a' : 'b'.
Because string is compatible with "a" | "b" and you don't use as const, TypeScript will use string. This is done to prevent compatibility issues with libraries. This is not obvious in your example. but take a look at how it works when you use objects:
export const test1 = {
    a: 'a',
    b: 'b'
};

type T1 = typeof test1; // { a: string, b: string } 


export const test2 = {
    a: 'a',
    b: 'b'
} as const;

type T2 = typeof test2; // { a: 'a', b: 'b' } 


It is the same, but as you can imagine, using 'a' | 'b' in object values instead of string by default could lead to many issues in existing libraries; this is why unless you use as const, TypeScript will go for string.

This doesn't make sense to me. Properties on constobject variables can still be reassigned (unless they're readonly), but const string variables can never be reassigned. Example: https://tsplay.dev/mA11Zm
